# Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function ( requirejs define method)

Tags: javascript, dojo, require, amd

I'm having some difficulty including the datatables plugin from https://datatables.net/manual/installation#Local-installation in my widget.

In the jquery.datatables.js there is a function that is supposed to assign jquery to the variable $

```
if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
        // AMD
        alert('AMD');
        define( ['assets/js/jquery/jquery-3.2.1'], function ( $ ) {
        alert('Common1');
        alert( $ );
        return factory( $, window, document );
    } );
```

However, my alert ( $ ) shows that $ is undefined where it's supposed to be the function constructor for JQuery

In any case, in the subsequent function of jquery.datatables.min there is a main function that takes in:

```
(function( $, window, document, undefined )
```

and in this function, on the first use of $ is where I get 
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Why am I getting this error and is it due to my define of the jquery causing this issue?

Even if I do:

```
var $ = require define( ['assets/js/jquery/jquery-3.2.1'])
```

right before the main function, I still don't get the $.fn.datatables function in the global?

I know this question is kind of a mess but I was hoping someone could give me pointers of where to start looking on how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to load jquery directly from CDN in the header and to not try to load using AMD.

Make sure jquery is the first library to be loaded in the header, example:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <!-- other scripts below -->
</head>
```